# Thymeleaf: Accessing externaized strings from Java code

Tags: java, maven, thymeleaf

I'm currently using Thymeleaf in a classic Maven project (no Spring) and I can't find in the documentation a simple way to acces externalized internationalisation string **from Java code** like, e.g Rails' `t()` function.

I found [the following](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html) tutorial but it really seems overengineered for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: But why from Java Code? If you want i18n strings, you want them probably in the frontend somehow, right? Then why not use Thymeleaf?

Comment: So if you are not using Spring MVC, what is your framework of use. There should be a way in that FW to do this. Post your code.

Comment: @MystyxMac: I have some specific use-cases which requires me to make a choice between a set of sentences to display. This, for lisibility reasons (and also conventions) has to be done in Java code.

Comment: So instead of using the default support you have to bolt on your own, good choice... But this is what `ResourceBundle`s are designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally adopted a raw solution, by just reading property files and extracting them into a `Properties` class.

This is not ideal as this obliges me to deal myself with the template name and locale to find the correct property but since this is a little project, this is no big deal. I hoped that Thymeleaf provided itself the correct set of locales but I've unhopefully no time to search.

Comment: As M. Deinum mentioned check out ResourceBundle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Answer (score 1):

The Thymeleaf documentations (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#a-multi-language-welcome) says the default configuration is to use properties files.

> This standard message resolver expects to find messages for /WEB-INF/templates/home.html in .properties files in the same folder and with the same name as the template, like:
>
> - /WEB-INF/templates/home_en.properties for English texts.
> - /WEB-INF/templates/home_es.properties for Spanish language texts.
> - /WEB-INF/templates/home_pt_BR.properties for Portuguese (Brazil)
>     language texts.
> - /WEB-INF/templates/home.properties for default texts
>     (if locale is not matched).

The properties file home_es.properties has an entry like

```
home.welcome=¡Bienvenido a nuestra tienda de comestibles!
```

And you use it like:

```
<p th:text="#{home.welcome}">Welcome to our grocery store!</p>
```